ECK Operator will not allow to remove data nodes because of PodDisruptionBudget
We have aws EKS version which we upgraded from 1.24 to 1.27. On top of it we are running ECK stack. We had increase our data nodes with help of helm command but at the time of decreasing the count of data nodes getting below error.
log.logger":"manager.eck-operator.controller.elasticsearch-controller","message":"Reconciler error","service.version":"1.9.1+75cb4d4d","service.type":"eck","ecs.version":"1.4.0","name":"elasticsearch","namespace":"elastic-systems","error":"no matches for kind \"PodDisruptionBudget\" in version \"policy/v1beta1\"","errorCauses":[{"error":"no matches for kind \"PodDisruptionBudget\" in version \"policy/v1beta1\""}],"error.stack_trace":"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.9.6/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:253\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\t/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.9.6/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:214"}

ECK operator is 1.9.1 and Elasticsearch 7.15. PDB version change from beta to v1 during upgrade processes. Any pointer would be highly appreciable.
